# Safari browser doesn’t work after using Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, safari

I realised this question might be more suited to Ask Different, so have posted it there also...

**iMac, with Safari Version 16.5 (18615.2.9.11.4)**

I had downloaded Jupyter notebook. I updated Python, and pip, using Terminal (Much trial and error! An impressive, but intimidating, beast).

Eventually got Jupyter notebook working. It uses ‘localhost’ (my computer as a server? Not sure what this means)

When I’d finished trying Jupyter notebook, I logged out of all (I think) the Safari tabs, and tried to open other websites.

Safari doesn’t work now. It can't open any sites.
It opens, but when I click in the search box, my ‘Favourites’ icons show, but are grayed out. (Reading list icons are also grayed out.)
When I type something in the search box and press enter, the coloured ‘progress line’, under the search box, just moves along a little, then stops/hangs.
Then I get this message:

*“  Safari can’t open the page [ . . . ] because Safari can’t establish a secure connection to the server  [ . . . ]  “*

Then a macOS update became available, which I allowed, thinking it might help the situation. It’s now Ventura 13.4
No change to Safari after the update, but Google Chrome browser works. I haven’t opened Jupyter notebook in Chrome, in case that gets messed up too.

I’ve removed all Safari website data (Safari/Privacy/Manage Website Data).
Deleted all Safari history.
Have done a Safari ’force quit’.
(There is no ‘Reset Safari’ option.)
I have the Safari ‘Develop’ tab showing, and have done ‘Empty Caches’ in there.
My time settings look ok.
All Ethernet Proxies are switched off. One Proxies ‘box’ says “Bypass proxy settings for these hosts and domains: *.local,169.254/16” (No idea what that means).
DNS Servers are set to 8.8.8.8 then 8.8.4.4.
Under TCP/IP I did ‘Renew DHCP Lease’.
I did ’Forget’ my network, then reconnected.

I don’t have a ‘normal, personal’ router - I’m in a Village, and use what we’re given. I didn’t know how to restart the router, so just switched the house mains power off, then on again.

I couldn’t find anything obvious on the Jupyter forum, or stack overflow.

I did try several suggestions from ChatGPT.

Maybe Safari isn’t broken - maybe it just can’t find its usual server?

All of which hasn’t helped. I don’t need Jupyter to work, anywhere  - it’s too complex for me.
Chrome’s still working, and I could live with that, but would prefer Safari to be fixed, if possible.

Thank you in advance.